# Restore Post Install Script setting on managed package patch

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, postinstall

Our managed package had a Post Install Script defined which was working fine.

For some undiagnosed reason (perhaps because we started using SFDX?) the Post Install Script setting was erased in a recent update to our patch development org.

Does anyone know how this setting could have been erased, and/or if there is a way to restore it short of moving to a new major release?

Thanks!

Comment: I've created an idea asking Salesforce to fix this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lPKTQA2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this by manually editing the `package.xml` in the metadata folder to add the missing settings before running `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`

More precisely:

1. Run `sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir output --packagename "Package Name"`
2. Edit `output/package.xml` to add `<postInstallClass>MyPostInstallClass</postInstallClass>` (and [other settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm) for the package) under the top-level `<Package>` element
3. Run `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir output`

To avoid doing this every time it's also possible to do the install in two steps:

1. Create a deploy directory without specifying the package (as suggested by @Dhanasekaran) and upload it:

   `sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir output --rootdir src/my-package
   sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir output`
2. Upload an overlay with only the package settings

   `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir config`

Where the `config` directory contains:

- `package.xml`

  With only the top level settings and the install/uninstall scripts, like:

  `<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
         <fullName>My Package</fullName>
         <postInstallClass>MyPostInstallClass</postInstallClass>
  </Package>`
- `classes`

  - `MyPostInstallClass.cls`
  - `MyPostInstallClass.cls-meta.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using to convert command with packagename option, try not using that option.

```
sfdx force:source:convert --rootdir src/force-app --outputdir output
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir output
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhanasekaran -- I believe this solution avoids overwriting the setting if it was still there, but I don't think it restores it once it is gone. See the answer I just posted for a solution to the latter problem